# Manage a very simple session when a user logs in using ExpressJS, MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, session

Currently I'm setting up a session in app.js and I'm trying to write to it and add a 'username' attribute with the user that has logged in to it, which I'd like to check later when doing certain actions. Currently it just sends a logged in! message:

```
var sessions = require('express-session');


app.use(express-session());
```

Then I'd like to write to it instead of nice:

```
app.get('/users/login', function(req, res) {
    const data = req.body;
    if(db.users.find({username:data}).length = 1){
        sess=req.session;
        res.send("Logged in!");
    }else{
        res.send("not nice!");
    }
})
```

Finding it very hard to understand compared to other sessions like PHP, in which it is very simple to write to it: $SESSION...

If someone could show me how to do this that'd be great! Thanks. I'd like to add that there's an error when I try to app.use(express-session()); although people say thats the way to initialize it online. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`= 1` appears to be a mistake. You don't want to *assign* to the length. There's no way the first branch can fail with how you're doing it.

What you mean is `if (...length == 1)`

Comment: Thanks, that appears to be a mistake, however I'm still trying to figure out how to set up the session and set it to the constant 'data'

Comment: This mistake means you'll only ever see "logged in" which was your description of the problem.